# Getting Values from array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying my best, but still not able to log the result at the end.

```
var arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];

function foo(arr) {
    var a = [], b = [], prev;

    arr.sort();
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(arr[i]);
            b.push(1);
        } else {
            b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }

    return [a, b];
}

var result = foo(arr);
var a = result[0]
var b = result[1]
var aa=a.split(",");
var ab=b.split(",");
var a = a.split(",").length;
var b = b.split(",").length;
for (c = 0; c < a; c++){
console.log(aa[c]);
console.log(ab[c]);}
```

I want to get values from two array result[0] and result[1] one by one in the loop.
Right now I am able to get all the values comma separated but when I split values, nothing shows up.

Comment: What is this code trying to do?

Comment: Can you please tell what is the expected output? It seems you want to remove the duplicates

Comment: So basically i want to get the unique no. from array and the no. of repetition of that particular value into another variable.

Comment: `a = result[0]` and `b = result[1]` are Arrays, not Strings. They have no `split()` method. Check the errors in your dev-tools.

Comment: How to split values of array? Can you give me a solution of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

```js
    var arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];
    
    function foo(arr) {
        var a = [], b = [], prev;
    
        arr.sort();
        for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
            if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
                a.push(arr[i]);
                b.push(1);
            } else {
                b[b.length-1]++;
            }
            prev = arr[i];
        }
    
        return [a, b];
    }
    
    var result = foo(arr);
    var a = result[0]
    var b = result[1]
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i++){ 
      console.log("Number: " + a[i] + "; Time repeated:"+ b[i]); }
```

Comment: Its working I tested before copying code here. @PiyushVerma - Or just give me the sample output how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty object to track the number of repetitions & an array to hold only unique values.Use `indexOf` to find if element already exist in `uniqArray`.

```js
var arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];
var repCount = {}, // to track number of repetitions 
  uniqArray = []; // holds only unique values

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  if (uniqArray.indexOf(item) == -1) {
   // id item is not present push it
    uniqArray.push(item)
  }
  // check if the object already have a key for example 2,4,5,9
  if (!repCount.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    repCount[item] = 1 // if not then create new key
  } else {
    // if it is there then increase the count
    repCount[item] = repCount[item] + 1
  }
})
console.log(uniqArray, repCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment...

> So basically i want to get the unique no. from array and the no. of repetition of that particular value into another variable

You can achieve this by using reduce function

```js
var arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];
var a = arr.reduce(function (acc, next) {
  acc[next] = acc[next] ? acc[next] + 1 : 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
    
console.log(a);
```

which gives you a hash with unique numbers as keys and their counts as values. From here you can easily break it into two arrays if you really need to..

Comment: I want the values in different variable
var a = unique value
var b = no. of repetitions

repectively